# One word for a watch enthusiast / watch lover

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the  one word for a person who is interested in wearing different types of "watches" and has a collection of various "watches".

Eg:

> John makes sure he wear a different watch each day to office. 
>   He is a _________.

Comment: What does your research show?  Please include it in your question.

Answer (score 7):

The [National Association of Watch and Clock Collectors](http://nawcc.org/) does not use any specific word for it, which in my world gives a strong indication that there is **no consensus on a single word**.¹

[Horologist](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/horologist) has been mentioned, and most horologists are probably clock enthusiast. All clock enthusiasts are however not horologists:

> :  a person skilled in the practice or theory of horology
>
> :  a maker of clocks or watches

[Horology](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/horology) again is defined as

> :  the science of measuring time
>
> :  the art of making instruments for indicating time

Depending on what you need the word for, you might be able to use Horologist in some cases, but definitely not all.

**EDIT:**

That being said, John Clifford mentioned **horophile** in the comments, and even though I wouldn't expect most people to know this word, it seems to be exactly what you are looking for. I did some research, and it does not exist in the merriam-webster dictionary, but there are a few online [dictionaries](http://www.yourdictionary.com/horophile) who do define it as:

> a person who has an obsession with timekeeping devices

There even is a blog by a clock enthusiast, called [The Horophile](http://www.thehorophile.com/)

The lack of this expression's mainstream usage is probably due to the limited numbers of horophiles, and/or maybe even it's phonetic similarity to someone who is into prostitutes.

¹ <sub>In comparison, the national association for stamp collectors are called [The American Philatelic Society](http://stamps.org/Home), and a stamp collector/enthusiast is called a *philatelist*.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a dictionary link, but a google search suggests several watch enthusiasts describe themselves as *horologophiles*.

A *horologist* is somebody who *makes* the watches.

Comment: Interesting, can you link to any of those search results?

Comment: http://forums.watchuseek.com/f71/what-kind-ist-you-943300.html